# How to keep consistency between two js files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xhtml

I have two html files (for add and edit) which contains js codes. These two files are identical except few js lines in its functions. Actually I don't like to have common code for both files. Is there a good way to handle this kind of situations ?

Example:

**(file one)**

```
<html>
     <title>title goes here</title>
      <javascript>

            $('#button1').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",       
                url: '/admin/test/checkcode',
                data: {code:code, id:id}, // in here there is an id
                async: false,                     
                success: function(data){
                }
            });
           }
      </script>  
     <body>

     </body>
</html>
```

**(file two)**

```
<html>
     <title>title goes here</title>
      <javascript>

            $('#button1').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",       
                url: '/admin/test/checkcode',
                data: {code:code}, // in here there is no id
                async: false,                     
                success: function(data){
                }
            });
           }
      </script>  
     <body>

     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try putting that JavaScript code into a separate file.  That way, you can just include the single JavaScript file into each of those pages... and only have to make changes to that one JavaScript file.

For reference, here is a way to include a JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript_file_here.js"></script>
```

Inside of that JavaScript file, there could be some type of basic function that takes parameters for that `data` value that is used in the `$.ajax()` call.  For example, something like:

```
function example(data1, data2) {
    // your code here
    // then just check for data1 and data2 (etc.)
    // to see what to include in the `data:`
}
```

Comment: Thanks summea for the reply. According to your answer then again I will have to write twice same ajax functions just because its one line    is changed ?

Comment: @Rohitha I see what you mean; in this case, you may also want to create some sort of function parameter in your JavaScript file... to let the code know what to include for that `data:` value.